# Using DateTime for a duration of time e.g. 45:00

Tags: c#

I'd just like to know if it is possible to use the DateTime type for durations such as 45:00 (45 minutes) or 120:00 (120 minutes). These values also need to be stored into a Local Sql Server DB. If it is possible, could anyone possibly hint how this could be done using Datetime, or if not just let me know a way it could be done using a different type.

Thank you in advance,
Jamie

Comment: [System.TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/269ew577.aspx)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use the [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) structure

```
TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan(0, 45, 0);
Console.WriteLine(interval.ToString());
```

For the database storing part, you could store the property [Ticks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.ticks.aspx) because a specific constructor for the TimeSpan structure allows to instantiate a new TimeSpan passing the Ticks value

```
long ticks = GetTimeSpanValueFromDb();
TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan(ticks);
```

I wish to add also that you need a `BIGINT T-SQL` datatype field to store a `long NET` datatype

Comment: Unless you need the kind of precision that's offered when storing durations in ticks, storing durations in seconds using an Int32 will reduce the amount of data transferred in read and write operations.

Comment: yes, but then how to restore the value? You need to apply a formula to rebuild the TimeSpan because you don't have a constructor that takes a seconds value and the property TotalSeconds is readonly. Just imagine how to transform a value in seconds that represents more than one day to a TimeSpan. Unless there is a compelling reason to keep small size in the database I prefer to have a simpler code

Comment: @frenchie Rereading the OP question, perhaps there is no need to re-read the value back. In that case I agree with you that is better to store the property TotalSeconds.

Comment: I am required to read the values from the database too so the TimeSpan option looks like a great solution. Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: I never see a reason to use the TimeSpan constructor `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(45)` and `TimeSpan.FromTicks(ticks)` are a lot more readable.

Comment: @Steve: a tick is one hundred nanoseconds. So if you're storing a duration of 3 minutes and 20 seconds in ticks then you're going to be storing a pretty big and long number, with nanosecond precision (rather useless in most cases). If you store the same duration in seconds, then it's just 200 seconds. Now if you're querying a list of durations and returning 100 items from the database, that's a lot of useless data going in and out; that's why I prefer storing durations in seconds. And as for converting 200 seconds to HH:MM:SS format, what's hard about that?

Comment: @frenchie - Describing nanoseconds as useless betrays a rather self centred world-view. You are *not* the only person building databases. It does you no harm and is vital for some applications. I would not describe 400 bytes as a lot of data in anything larger than an engine management system. Rather more than this is wasted on every http header and pointless round trip. Carriers charge in whole packets, for which the unit is generally 1 or 2Kb. Optimisation is the enemy of resilience.

Answer (score 1):

I store durations in seconds in the database and then convert to HH:MM:SS format when comes time to display the data.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `TimeSpan` instead? You can convert them to `Ticks` (int), store them in the db and the reverse the process when you need the value.

Answer (score 0):

This is merely a matter of interpretation. SQL Server stores datetime as two four byte integers. One is a signed int count of days from a reference date, the other is an unsigned time of day such that 32bits exactly maps 24 hours. Without the implicit epoch, this isn't a datetime, it's a duration. Nothing prevents you from interpreting it that way.

Of course, it would be more convenient to pick a unit and simply use a float. This is what Windows does, storing datetime as a number of days from a reference date expressed as an 8-byte float (a double).

Personally I don't like "day" as a unit of time. The rotational period of our planet is *not* constant, and it is necessary to mess about with leap seconds to maintain the illusion that there are 86400 seconds in every day. A better choice is the SI unit, the second, which is defined in terms of repeatable, invariant physical constants.

Better again would be the picosecond, since we could dump the double and use an int64, with all the attendant arithmetical and comparative performance advantages. Depiction in mixed human scale units (yyyy mmm d  HH:mm:ss) is already something of a trial. Mapping functions that currently work with fractional days could trivially be scaled to microseconds, although the compensation for leap seconds and leap days would have to be rewritten.

I say picosecond because this is the finest division that fits in 64 bits while encompassing a useful span of time (50,000 years). Femto fits, but fifty years isn't wide enough. I know that eventually there be a year 50K problem but frankly I doubt anyone but archeologists will care about records from 50,000 years ago.